# Wordpress Change Text Of Something

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have an area on my wordpress site which says for comments 'Your email address will not be published.' I want to remove this. The problem is I have searched through all files in editor, and I cannot locate this text. So how else can I find it?

Is there any code I could use in comments or functions which remove this.

Code:

```
<p class="comment-notes">
<span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Where does it come from? Do you have a link to that page?

Comment: I got that code by using firebug on firefox to view the code.

Comment: I meant is there some type of forms plugin that is being used to create a form? If we had a link, it would be a lot easier to give advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following to your style.css file:

```
.comment-notes #email-notes {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Shaun, code corrected above please try again